# How to disable floating while showing error in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/productLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/product"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_padding_width_height_6"
      android:cursorVisible="false"
      android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
      android:hint="@string/product"
      android:inputType="none"
      android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_width_height_2"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_padding_width_height_2"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_m" />
```

```
private boolean validateFields() {
        if (mCategory.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            mCategoryLayout.setError("Please select a category");
        else if (mProducts.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            mProductsLayout.setError("Please select a product");
        else if (mSerialNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            mSerialNumberLayout.setError("Please enter the serial number");
        else
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

I have implemented click listener for the `EditText`,So I don't want float the `EditText` label to top while setting error on `TextInputLayout`. How do I disable that ?

Comment: what do You mean with floating?

Comment: the label animation -http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-floating-labels-for-edittext/

Comment: from the docs, I guess You have to use for Your TextInputLayout the method setHintAnimationEnabled(false); programmatically or android.support.design:hintAnimationEnabled="false" in xml....

Comment: Animation gone but the label is still floating to top

Comment: on which API You are building Your app? This was an issue on API<23 and is fixed since API 23....

Comment: buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: and do You compile in gradle against the same version like this: compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0' ?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: so there must be something else....please update Your code, show how You have disabled it. I think if You use a minSDK build version <23m, it doesn´t work......I guess...

Answer (score 4):

Starting version 23.2.0 of the Support Library you can call

```
setHintEnabled(false)
```

or putting it in your TextInputLayout xml as such :

```
app:hintEnabled="false"
```

Though the name might makes you think it removes all hints, it just remove the floating one.

Related docs and issue: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setHintEnabled(boolean)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181590

Comment: This will remove hint view, so the layout will move up.

Answer (score 3):

If someone wants preserve floating label but don't collapse them when we use `setError()` on `TextInputLayout` I found a hacky solution that works with support `25.4.0`. Unfortunately it can be corrupted in newer versions.

```java
public class HackedTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    private int forceExpandedHintBlockFlags = 0;

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);

        if (child instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) child).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getError()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                        forceExpandedHintBlockFlags++;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getError()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                        forceExpandedHintBlockFlags--;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setError(@Nullable CharSequence error) {
        forceExpandedHintBlockFlags++;
        super.setError(error);
        forceExpandedHintBlockFlags--;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getError() {
        // the main hack is right here
        return forceExpandedHintBlockFlags > 0 ? null : super.getError();
    }

    @Override
    public void setHintTextAppearance(int resId) {
        forceExpandedHintBlockFlags++;
        super.setHintTextAppearance(resId);
        forceExpandedHintBlockFlags--;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        forceExpandedHintBlockFlags++;
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        forceExpandedHintBlockFlags--;
    }
}
```

---

The main hack is based on source of `TextInputLayout`. `setError()`, `TextWatcher` and few other functions invokes `updateLabelState()` where we have below condition:

```java
if (hasText || this.isEnabled() && (isFocused || isErrorShowing)) {
    if (force || this.mHintExpanded) {
        this.collapseHint(animate);
    }
} ...
```

The key here is the value of `isErrorShowing = !TextUtils.isEmpty(this.getError())`. So if we temporary *disable* `getError()` then we always have `isErrorShowing == false` in that place. *Voila* :)

Answer (score 0):

> Try this :

```
mCategoeyLayout.setHintAnimationEnabled(false);
```

> Later (like on click of Edittext)

```
mCategoeyLayout.setHintAnimationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  private boolean validateFields() {
    if (mCategory.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        mCategoryLayout.setError("Please select a category");
    else if (mProducts.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        mProductsLayout.setError("Please select a product");
    else if (mSerialNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        mSerialNumberLayout.setError("Please enter the serial number");
    else
        return true;
    return false;
}
```