# Do not move hint to the top when calling setError() of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I have a layout file with a TextInputLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fullnameEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="26dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

When I call the setError() method on the TextInputLayout the hint goes to the top as if the TextInputLayout would have focus.

I would like to leave the hint untouched while setting the error. It should look something like this:

[image: design]

Any ideas how to build this layout?

Comment: How does the TextInputLayout look in code?

Comment: I added the content of my xml file

Comment: @buellas you required output of above image right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with alternative way , you can call `setError()` on `OnCreate()`

```
 mTextInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.fullname);
 mTextInputLayout.setError("Enter Your Full Name");
```

and when you want to show the Error do this

```
mTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
```

**and this will fix your problem with the hint**

```
   if (mTextInputLayout.isErrorEnabled()){
         mTextInputLayout.setHintEnabled(false);
      }else {
         mTextInputLayout.setHintEnabled(true);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
The important thing is calling mTextInputLayout.setHintEnabled(boolean); setError() doesn't needs to be called on OnCreate().

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your own `MyTextInputLayout` class extending from `TextInputLayout`.

In that class you will have to control when to show or not the hint, overriding the custom behavior that shows hint when error appears.

Nice start point in another answer from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521653/2174489